# Set base 'shop' URL to something else in Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am completely new to Craft and to be honest, really struggling to get my head around how it all works at the moment.

I've got loads of, what I feel, is quite basic questions that should be relatively straight forward but after searching numerous documentation and online posts, can't find out how to do any of it.

So figured asking here might be the quickest way of learning how to work with the platform.

So in a development environment, I've got Craft CMS set up with the Pro version of Commerce. By default, this comes set up at /shop/.

What do I have to do exactly in order to change the 'shop' URL to something else, for example /store/?

I tried duplicating the 'shop' directory as 'store' and whilst the pages seem to load at /store/*, the templates are still being served from /shop/* (tested by modifying them).

If someone could list step by step the correct process for changing this, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the demo templates are set up they are a series of included sub-templates.
So you would need to change the references to `shop/` for each of the `{% include %}` statements.

Try doing a find/replace on the templates within your `/store` directory. See what that does.

Craft/Commerce places no restriction on how you name things. You don't need to use the demo templates at all if you don't want to. You can name them and place them wherever you like.

Comment: I had already tried that but the frontend page I am seeing at the /store/ URL is being served from the /shop/ directory still (I made an edit to the _includes/nav.html in /store/ and it made no difference but did the same to the one in /shop/ and could see the edit in the frontend). It's as if there is some of setting that specifies where to serve the files from.

Comment: You were right, I had to modify variables like this one `{% extends 'shop/_layouts/main' %}` to the 'store' path in order for the header, nav etc to be loaded from the correct place.

Comment: Yep those are pulling in the partial templates. It's a path to the partial. As mentioned, the template can be set up however you like. Personally, I'm not a fan of the way the demo templates are done - it's far too complex for a newcomer. But it you work through them diligently then you'll pick things up soon enough.